# Updating asyncoperation fields in Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to update AsyncOperation fields using REST API in Dynamics 365 CRM. But there is a problem.
If I try to update *any* field by request, for example

```
PATCH /api/data/v9.0/asyncoperations(GUID) HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
OData-Version: 4.0
If-Match: *

{
    "name":"new async operation name"
}
```

In response I receive this error message (with different codes for different GUIDs obviously):

> The state transition requested is not valid for the current state.
> Current state: 3, current status: 32, target state: 3.

Even if I did not make any changes to statecode and statuscode fields.
I can not update field even if update only 1 field in a time by

```
PUT /api/data/v9.0/asyncoperations(GUID)/name
```

with same response.
Updating other fields with "@odata.bind" does not work too.

What am I doing wrong? Maybe there is any header I miss or something. And is it even possible to update information for AsyncOperation entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot update asyncoperations Entity for field Name.

This operation is not supported on asyncoperations  Entity.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you. Almost every writable field for asyncoperation is not valid for update.